# Should I edit spam as well as flag it?

Tags: support

If I see spam posted as an answer, I should flag it for moderator attention/deletion.

Should I also edit it, to hide the spammy text?

Comment: Removing spam/abusive text before a question/answer is deleted can affect the automated spam/abuse detection (users will not flag it as spam/abusive). See [Should Spam posts be edited?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110030).

Answer (score 3):

There are SE people who run a network 'bot which looks for spam.

They advise me that it's enough to flag it, and that it isn't necessary to also edit it.

- [Is it OK to edit obvious spam to break links?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/263051/49942)
- [Should spam posts be edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110030/139866)

Comment: It is in fact preferable to *not* edit it, since edits open the post up to rollbacks, and rollbacks can undo flagging and delay the time until the spam post gets eliminated.